# Spring STS installation error (Ubuntu)

Tags: spring, java

When I run *STS* after the installation of *spring STS* on Ubuntu 14, I get the error message below:

> *Version 1.7.0_111 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.8 or greater is required.*

I have **openjdk 8** installed.

What can I do now?

Comment: check which version of java is in your path... use this `whereis java` to check that.

Comment: Apparently you have JDK 7 installed and you need to install the 1.8 version. Follow something like http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/

Comment: Not really.I have installed JDK 8

Comment: How have you verified that you have openjdk 8 installed? What does `java -version` output?

Comment: problem is solved. thanks a lot . I have uninstall all the jdk then install oracle jdk 8.then it is worked successfully.